# Can I stop cipher from wiping free space right after writing 0x00?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive-recovery, wipe

Can I stop the cipher utility from wiping free space on a large drive just after it finishes writing 0x00?

Comment: Too bad there is not a switch to only do only one overwrite....please upvote my answer, thanks.

Comment: Please up vote the accepted solution @reaffer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I do it all the time, open task manager and Kill the process cipher.exe.